# How to disable terminal fullscreen padding

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim

When I run vim at full screen mode in `gnome-terminal`, actually it is not *really* full screen.

There is a little padding on the right and bottom, with the terminal background color.

You can reach the original image to see it more clearly.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: What version of `vim` is this?

Comment: Actually this problem is not about vim... Whatever application I run, the padding remains the same. But in `xterm`, there is no such problem.

Comment: So what terminal emulator is this?

Comment: The default one in Ubuntu, `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make vim inside the terminal actually full screen, unless you're lucky enough that both the width and the height are multiples of the cell size (plus the fixed UI chrome taken into account).

The terminal is a text grid, and if you force it to a maximized size which doesn't match this grid then there's necessarily a margin which is inaccessible to vim.

You probably don't realize it with xterm because xterm's background color is the same black as vim's background color; whereas gnome-terminal's is different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the CLI version, but there's the gVim [VullScreen](https://github.com/KabbAmine/vullScreen.vim) addon on Github that's pretty nice.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

There's still the problem of the right scrolling bar. 
Alternatively you can use xTerm but you'll have to patch it and compile it yourself, [here's the link.](http://www.davidsimmons.com/soft/xtermhacks/#fullscreen)

Another option yet would be to use a tty terminal by using the CTRL+ALT+F1 to F6 shortcut, but that's not probably what you were looking for.

Comment: The question is about fixing the padding issue. Look closer at the image @Hao posted, it has a *purple* colour padding on the bottom and right. Toggling fullscreen is not an issue. You don't need a plugin for that, you can configure whatever keybinding you like, `F11`, is often the default. See https://github.com/gerardroche/dotfiles/blob/master/src/bin/configure-ubuntu-keybindings

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution.

This will **fix the right side padding issue**, possibly only for some versions of Gnome.

In a custom theme create tweak the gtk style  `gtk-3.0/gtk.css` with the following:

```
/**
 * Fixes some padding issues in Vim + Terminal
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

VteTerminal,
TerminalScreen {
    border: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    -VteTerminal-inner-border: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

#### Full guide

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Create a file named `.themes/galactica/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` put the css shown above in it.
3. Open the Tweak Tool and set the shell theme to "Galactica".
4. Restart